# php array , how to display array data in email

Tags: php

```
$qua1 = "5";

$queryNotification= "SELECT * from stock where stockQty <= :qua1 ";
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare($queryNotification);
$stmt3->bindParam(':qua1',$qua1);
$stmt3->execute();

while ($queryNotRow = $stmt3->fetch()){

$a=array("Qty"=>$queryNotRow['stockQty'],"name "=>$queryNotRow['stockName'],"cb "=>$queryNotRow['stockPrice']);
// $array[$queryNotRow['stockQty']] = $queryNotRow['stockName'];

foreach( $a as $row ):
$b = "stockqty = " . $queryNotRow['stockQty'] . " and StockName = " . $queryNotRow['stockName'] . "<br>";
endforeach;

echo $b;

}
```

If I add send email code inside the foreach loop , the system will send many email according on how many data. How can I only send all the data by ONE EMAIL??

Comment: probably with print_r($a); ?

Comment: i want get display like  Stockqty = ? and StockName = ?

Comment: [0] => Array
        (
            [Qty] => 5
            [name ] => 5
          
        )         printr will show this ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach( $a as $row ):
    echo "stockqty = " . $row['Qty'] . " and StockName = " . $row['name'] . "<br>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: if i want to send this all data through ONLY one email, is it possible??

Comment: of course it is. instead of echoing it, you can create string with those variables. I believe we have answered your question and you can go from here. 

If theres new problem you're facing, browse thru previously asked questions ( theres a lot covering these things ), in case of no luck with that, consider posting new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$a=array("Qty"=>$queryNotRow['stockQty'],"name "=>$queryNotRow['stockName']);

foreach($a as $key=>$data){
echo 'stock'.$key.'='.$data.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: get this error (Notice: Array to string conversion in))

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$a[] = array(
        "Qty" => 1,
        "name " => 2
    );

foreach ($a as $row) {
        echo $row['Qty']."===".$row['name'];
}
```